# Cannot write Image object returned from RMagick gem append method to Amazon S3

Tags: ruby, amazon-s3, imagemagick, rmagick

I am reading three images using the RMagick gem and then adding them to an `ImageList`

```
imagelist = ImageList.new

imagelist << Image.read(path1)[0]
imagelist << Image.read(path2)[0]
imagelist << Image.read(path3)[0]
```

Then I combined these three images with the `append` method

```
combined_image = imagelist.append(false)
```

Then I try to write this image to Amazon S3:

```
AWS::S3::S3Object.store(filename, combined_image, bucket)
```

However, I get this error which prevents me from successfully writing the image to S3:

```
undefined method `size' for #<Magick::Image:0x00000101994498>
```

I played around with RMagic in the console, and I found that when you `append` images in an `ImageList`, it returns an `Image` that seems to omit its size in bytes.

How can I modify this image so that I can write it to S3?

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. The trick was to turn the `combined_image` to a Binary Large Object by calling `to_blob` on it.

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you to check whether `combined_image.display` shows the desired appended image to you or not.
If it does, AWS::S3 must store the image file like any other general storing syntax of cloud.